# Bash read line stops in the middle of the file

Tags: bash, shell, ssh

I've created a bash script to connect to a number of servers and execute a program. The ips and quantities per IP should be read from a config file that is structured like this:

```
127.0.0.1 10
127.0.0.1 1
127.0.0.1 3
```

etc

```
j=$((0))
while IFS=' ' read -r ip quantity; do
  echo "${ip} x ${quantity}";

  for (( i = 1; i <= quantity; i++ ))
  do
    echo "ssh root@${ip} cd test/libhotstuff && ./examples/hotstuff-app --conf ./hotstuff.gen-sec${j}.conf > log${j} 2>&1"
    ssh root@"${ip}" "cd test/libhotstuff && ./examples/hotstuff-app --conf ./hotstuff.gen-sec${j}.conf > log${j} 2>&1" &
    j=$((j+1))
  done

  sleep 1

done < ips
```

I noticed that this while loop breaks if the execution takes too long. If I put sleep for 1s here it will stop after the first execution. If I remove it, but the inner loop takes too long a subset of the lines will not be read.

What is the problem here?

Comment: I didn't know that was possible =D

Comment: [BashFAQ](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) is a godsend.. Also, worth reading the whole [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html) through before writing code. You'll save time and headache in the end.

Comment: I adjusted it, that made the script much clearer, thanks. But the problem still occurs.

Comment: add `set -x` before the loop and see if the debugging output offers a clue. Also setting before a command helps log that command as run without having to maintain an echo and the actual command execution, in case it changes...

Comment: From the debug output it seems that it stops working after the first ssh succeeds.

Comment: Should be "i <= $quantity" or is that a typo ?

Comment: wait at which location of the script? at the place of the sleep?

Comment: Yes, I'm running an interactive protocol between those servers. That's why I want to run those.

Comment: With the wait it's the same result as without.

Comment: I have a long "sleep" at the end and afterwards another ssh to kill all the processes.

Comment: Without the wait, it will run them in background and exit immediately.

Comment: @TedLyngmo without placing it in the background it's stuck undefinitely after the first ssh

Comment: The application is not supposed to quit. It's supposed to run on the other side until I kill it. That's why I made it non-interactive

Comment: Might be me misunderstanding what "non interactive" means too

Comment: they are supposed to run for around 6 minutes (basically the sleep time afterwards)

Comment: Maybe you want the `&` inside the quotes?

Comment: Didn't help, even tried inside and outside the quote

Comment: The relevant BashFaq for this is [BashFaq #89](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/089)

Comment: @thatotherguy Thanks! I was too into my own world when trying to figure this out so doing the correct searches never occured to me. After having played the drums for a few hours, I finally found the option. :) I'll leave my answer here even though there is a dupe since I tailor made it for OP and I added at least one other option that often messes up batch `ssh` jobs if missing (the `StrictHostKeyChecking=no` one).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a version that starts your background processes with a 1 second delay between each, waits 6 minutes before killing them one by one, with a 1 second delay between each, to give them approximately the same running time.

You should also add some options to `ssh` to prevent it from interfering with `stdin` and terminate your loop prematurely while running.

- `-n`
  Prevents reading from stdin
- `-oBatchMode=yes`
  Passphrase/password querying will be disabled
- `-oStrictHostKeyChecking=no`
  Connect to host even if the host key has changed

```
#!/bin/bash

sshopts=(-n -oBatchMode=yes -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no)

j=0
pids=()
while IFS=$' \t\n' read -r ip quantity; do
  echo "${ip} x ${quantity}";

  for (( i = 0; i < quantity; ++i ))
  do
    remotecmd="cd test/libhotstuff && ./examples/hotstuff-app --conf ./hotstuff.gen-sec${j}.conf > log${j} 2>&1"
    localcmd=(ssh ${sshopts[@]} root@${ip} "$remotecmd")
    echo "${localcmd[@]}"
    "${localcmd[@]}" &
    # store the background pid
    pids+=($!)
    (( ++j ))
    sleep 1
  done

done < ips

seconds=360
echo "running ${pids[@]} in the background $seconds seconds"

sleep $seconds

echo "telling the background processes to terminate"
for pid in ${pids[@]}
do
    echo killing $pid
    kill $pid
    sleep 1
done

echo "waiting for all the background processes to terminate"
wait
echo Done
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223790/discussion-on-answer-by-ted-lyngmo-bash-read-line-stops-in-the-middle-of-the-fil).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a version that offloads the loop and parallel processes to the remote shell script. Generate a remote shell script from a HereDocument with quantity, and wait for all the background processes to terminate before exiting.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

while IFS=$' \t\n\r' read -r ip quantity || [ -n "$quantity" ]
do
  {
# When satisfied by the output:
# Ucomment the line below and delete its following line with the echo and cat
#    ssh "root@$ip" <<EOF
    echo ssh "root@$ip"; cat <<EOF
if cd test/libhotstuff
then
  i=$quantity
  until
    i=\$((i - 1))
    [ \$i -lt 0 ]
  do
    ./examples/hotstuff-app \\
      --conf "./hotstuff.gen-sec\$i.conf" >"log\$i" 2>&1 &
  done
  wait
fi
EOF
  } &
done <ips

# Wait for all child processes to terminate
wait
echo "All child ssh done!"
```

Another way replacing the dynamic HereDocument by an inline shell script called with a quantity argument:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

while IFS=$' \t\n\r' read -r ip quantity || [ -n "$quantity" ]; do
  echo ssh "root@$ip" sh -c '
if cd test/libhotstuff
then
  i=0
  while [ $i -lt "$1" ]; do
    ./examples/hotstuff-app --conf "./hotstuff.gen-sec$i.conf" >"log$i" 2>&1 &
    i=$((i + 1))
  done
  wait
fi
' _ "$quantity" &
done <ips

# Wait for all child processes to terminate
wait
echo "All child ssh done!"
```

Comment: That doesn't work because I need the ongoing variable j so it's conf${j} not conf${i}

Comment: @user2524707 did you even try to run the script that will just print what it would send via ssh?

Comment: Yes I did run it. that worked smoothly